# Find folder using batch

Tags: windows-explorer, batch, libraries, search-folder

I'm trying to make a script that helps to go through a big library with lots of folders, names and numbers. 
The part numbers are divided in 4 parts **XXX.XX.XX.XXXX**. 
To help the searching the library folders are set like this: (example names) **100_Vegetal\01_Flower\01_Red\0001_Rose**

My issue is the name of the folders, if the folder was only called "100" it would be easy to go through. Here is the code that I use to separate the part number and to try to open the folder.

```
set /p pnr="Please enter the PNR : " 
echo %pnr%
echo %pnr:~0,3% 
echo %pnr:~4,2%
echo %pnr:~7,2%
echo %pnr:~10,4%
explorer ".library\%pnr:~0,3%(*)"
```

I would like to open a folder that has the first 3 digits of the part number.
Can you please help me with that issue. I tried with the star but it open the explorer...

Thank you.

Comment: Use `for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%pnr%") do Echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D` to split the pnr into four for meta variables %%A..%%D

Comment: Explorer doesn't accept wild-cards in a passed directory name: you need something like `for /d %%d in (".library\%pnr:~0,3%*") do start /w explorer "%%d"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the numbers from the pnr are unique in the folder tree,
the following batch will open directly the folder matching all 4 numbers by iterating with successive `for /d loops`

Take care, the for meta variables distinguish between upper/lower case,
so the pnr is split into `%%A..%%D` and the found folders are in `%%a..%%d`

Sample tree on my ram drive A:

```
> tree
A:.
└───.library
    └───100_Vegetal
        └───01_Flower
            └───01_Red
                └───0001_Rose
```

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\26\SU_1370234.cmd
@Echo off 
set "Base=A:\.library"
set /p pnr="Please enter the PNR : " 
:: set pnr=100.01.01.0001
echo %pnr%

:: reset Level variables
for /l %%L in (1,1,4) do Set "Level%%L="

:: first split pnr, then dive into folders
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%pnr%" ) Do (
  for /d %%a in ("%Base%\%%A*") Do (Set Level1=%%a
    for /d %%b in ("%%a\%%B*") Do  (Set Level2=%%b
      for /d %%c in ("%%b\%%C*") Do (Set Level3=%%c
        for /d %%d in ("%%c\%%D*") Do (Set Level4=%%d
          Explorer "%%d
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
:: set Level
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\26\SU_1370234.cmd
Please enter the PNR :
100.01.01.0001
Level1=A:\.library\100_Vegetal
Level2=A:\.library\100_Vegetal\01_Flower
Level3=A:\.library\100_Vegetal\01_Flower\01_Red
Level4=A:\.library\100_Vegetal\01_Flower\01_Red\0001_Rose
```

Explorer opens here in `A:\.library\100_Vegetal\01_Flower\01_Red\0001_Rose`

Comment: How can I "hide" the Level path ?

Comment: Simply comment/remove the last line, it was implemented to help if no matching folder for all 4 pnr elements is found.

Comment: You mean the set Level ?

Comment: Yes, changed above.

Comment: If I put it as a comment it gives me a syntax error...

Comment: It runs here as posted above without flaw.

Comment: In comment I had an error but by deleting the line it works just fine thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command with the `/S /B /AD` parameters in a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and make it recursively traverse the source folder for ***directories only*** and then iterate those folders with the numbers you type using a wildcard to be opened in Explorer.

### Script Example

```
set /p pnr="Please enter the PNR : " 
set pnr=%pnr:~0,3%
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%a IN ('DIR /S /B /AD ".library\%pnr%*"') DO explorer "%%~fa"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  > ```
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)